# How to remove the default eclipse and setup new eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have a eclipse. I removed default eclipse from `/usr/lib` as,

```
sudo apt-get remove eclipse
```

Then I copied my eclipse folder to `/usr/lib` and tried to launch it as,

```
sudo eclipse
```

But I am getting the following error,

```
usr/bin/eclipse: 35: exec: /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse: not found
```

My eclipse which I copied is present in `/usr/lib`. Why am I getting this error? My requirement is I have to remove the default eclipse and launch my own eclipse from `/usr/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to purge it, that way it will remove all the configurations saved in your home folder.

`sudo apt-get purge eclipse`
and then
`sudo apt-get install eclipse`

Comment: Can you please be more specific? I already have my eclipse which I copied to /usr/lib. Now if I do sudo apt-get purge eclipse and then sudo apt-get install eclipse, what will happen to my eclipse which is present in /usr/lib ?

Comment: is eclipse installed files in /usr/lib they will be removed when you do apt-get remove, purge will do that aswell, but I can see you already ran remove before. make a copy if not sure

Comment: why do you care about what you have in /usr/lib, you said you wanted to reinstall it, right?